# Why does ssm:sendmessage always throw error when running imagebuilder pipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, amazon-imagebuilder

I've been trying to get imagebuilder working to run some built-in and custom components doing some very basic installs. I go through the whole setup process via click-ops run the pipeline and get the following error:

```
Error while calling ssm:SendCommand: InvalidInstanceId
```

I've verified I have the ssm, ssmmessages, and ec2messages endpoints created in the vpc, have full ssm access policy (as well as others just googling) attached to the role used by imagebuilder, and that I've allowed the proper ports in the security group.

I know this is a common question on stackoverflow, but when the Iam roles are not the issue then what other resources need to be modified to either use ssm or comnpletely bypass this?

More than that, I've tried to override ssm by including a bash script in the "user-data" section of imagebuilder, but this doesnt work either, even after stopping the instance, updating the script via ec2, and starting it again. Insight on this would be appreciated.